# Delete query error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I have to tables A and B 
Structure of A:

```
ID | B_ID | data1 | data2
```

Where B_ID is the primary key from table B

Structure of B:

```
ID | datax | data3
```

And I'm trying to delete from An every row where B_ID not exists in B table.
The query I'm trying to execute is

```
DELETE A FROM A JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM `produs` A
    left join B b on B.ID=A.B_ID
    where B.ID is null
)
```

Select query is working fine but when I execute the above statement I get this message:

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Note: I want delete query to work with JOIN not IN.

Comment: just add the alias after the declaration..

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do like

```
DELETE A FROM A JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM `produs` A
left join B b on B.ID=A.B_ID
where B.ID is null
) analiasname;
```